# mysql php: how to properly save a query result

Tags: php, mysql

my code:

```
$db = new PDO('mysql:host='.DBx.';dbname='.DBx.';charset=utf8', DBx, DBx);
$sql = "SELECT  max(date_insert) FROM OrderAUS LIMIT 1" ;
$val = $db->query($sql);
```

the result of the query should be one date, i need to put it in a $variable (just the date, not an array of results).
Can you please show me the correct way to do it?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.error-handling.php --- http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to tell MYSQL like this

```
$db = new PDO('mysql:host='.DBx.';dbname='.DBx.';charset=utf8', DBx, DBx);
$sql = "SELECT  max(date_insert) as date FROM OrderAUS LIMIT 1" ;
$var = $db->query($sql);
$result = $var->fetchColumn();
print_r($result);
```

Comment: it says error: Call to undefined method PDO::fetchColumn()

Comment: Edited my answer . is it working now ?

Comment: yes, thx. now i need to subtract 1h to date.
something like 
$result->sub(DateInterval::createFromDateString('45 minutes'))->format('Y-m-d H:i');
but it says that result must be an object. any idea?

Comment: yeah sure!! .. :D if the answer is ok for this question , Can you please mark this as correct answer and then create an detailed question about what you need next ? ... That would be great! It would be helpfull to understand a full detailed question ..